# iPhone 5 Vs iPod Touch 5G iOS development differences?

Tags: iphone-5, ipod-touch

I am tasked to develop applications on a iPhone 5. However due to some office workspace restriction, we are not allowed to insert a sim card into a iPhone 5. (we will be using wifi for development)

Is there any difference in terms of software development (certain api restriction, or computability issues) that a developer may face if he/she is to develop a iPhone 5 application on a iPod touch. I'm trying to justify reasons to get a iPhone 5 :P

I've noted that GPS chipset is not available on a iPod Touch 5g, however wifi triangulation is workign for iPod touch 5g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test offline GPS navigation and cellular network on iPod Touch.

And mostly they are weaker than their phone counterparts, so you can optimize it on a weaker device, and it will more likely to run smooth on more powerful devices.